# blank page after form submission on chrome for iphone

Tags: iphone, google-chrome

Having a strange issue with chrome for iphone (19.0.1084.60). The site works fine, except from one specific problem: The user gets to a page with a small javascript snippet that submits a form:

```
<script>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
window.onload = function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    document.forms['my_form'].submit();                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
</script>
```

The js submission works fine, but when the the next page is loaded, chrome on iphone shows a blank page. The loading bar is stuck at around 80% and the network-indication spinner keeps spinning...

This doesn't happen on chrome on linux or with safari on iphone either.

If I go to the address bar and reload the page, it displays it just fine...

Any ideas how to approach / debug this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like on the latest update from Chrome for iOS this problem no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your folders to permissions 0755 and your files to 0644?

I was having this issue on the iPhone in Safari, and that fixed the problem for me.

As a note this was over a 3G connection on iOS 5.

Comment: Thanks, but the file/folder permissions were always right, and didn't seem to make a difference. The latest version of Chrome for iOS seemed to have solved it though.